# Why this div goes over its parent when i apply a padding left or right on it?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

This is the second issue i have on the right side of a container using the very usefull `twitter-bootstrap`, but this time, i have been able to reproduce it on jsFiddle!

[Here is the link](http://jsfiddle.net/YHPeB/1/), as you can see in the CSS window, i apply a `padding-left` and a `padding-right` on a div, the left one make the div going over its parent on the right side, and if i only apply a `padding-right`, i get the same.

I can't understand this behavior and this is probably the same issue i meet on another project, how to avoid that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working [example](http://jsfiddle.net/YHPeB/3/)

All you have to do is specify a width. I've added a border just to see the div.

```
#child {
    width: auto;
    border: 1px solid red;
    padding-left: 50px;
    padding-right: 50px; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The behavior you're observing stems from two facts: first, that the Bootstrap rows are set to `width: 100%`. Second, that they use the default box-sizing value, `content-box`.

Box-sizing is the property that determines how the width of a block element is calculated. When it's set to content-box, it only factors in the width of the content, and not the margin, padding, or border. What follows is that the padding you're setting is adding to the total width, making it greater than 100%, and making it jut out beyond the parent.

For the behavior you want set the `box-sizing` to `padding-box`. This causes the calculated width of the element to include the padding.

[**View it on JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/V9kdz/)

```
#child {
  ...
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

For more on the box-sizing attribute, I recommend two great CSS resources: Chris Coyier's [CSS Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/) and the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/box-sizing).